# bind two bindingsources, which are associated with ORM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding

I have form with DataGridView.
This datagrid use this binding:

```
        clientBindingSource.DataSource = from asd in db.Clients select new MainGridHelper()
            {
                Client = asd
            };
```

MainGridHelper have some properties and useful methods. But then I add new client from another form:

```
        _client = new Client();
        clientBindingSource.DataSource = _client;
        //...
        DBContext.Clients.InsertOnSubmit(_client);
        DBContext.SubmitChanges();
```

So, I use DataGridView.Refresh() after add client.
I have new null Client in first BindingSource, but row added (empty cells).
I dont want merge MainGridHelper and Clients classes.
How I can fix this without new LINQ query?

Sorry, if it is an easy question.

Comment: first bindingSource for main form, second for child form. ;)
So, clientBindingSource.Insert(new MainGridHelper {Client = _returned}) works fine

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen, and how does that differ from what is happening now?

Comment: I want new correctly row after add new instance of client, now I have new row with empty cells. If I rerun application, I have all rows correcе.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (and that's a big if), just adjust the original LINQ query to exclude the nulls:

```
clientBindingSource.DataSource = from asd in db.Clients 
                                 where asd != null
                                 select new MainGridHelper()
        {
            Client = asd
        };
```